# HTML form submission - basic premise

Tags: html, forms

Let's say I'm at `http://www.domain.com/page.html`.

I want to submit this form:

```
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="https://DifferentSite.com/processForm.aspx">
....
</FORM>
```

Is the server at `www.domain.com` actually seeing any of the information from the form at ANY point?  Or, is this coming directly from the client directly to `DifferentSite.com`?

The reason I ask, for example as shown above, the form submission calls an HTTPS, and the site I'm on is HTTP only (no SSL).  It also has PCI compliance implications if the domain.com server does see and transmit the form info (even if encrypted).

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the server at www.domain.com actually seeing any of the information from the form at ANY point?

Not intrinsically, but it could sniff it with JavaScript before submission (or change the URL since that is set by that site).

> Or, is this coming directly from the client directly to DifferentSite.com?

Yes

> The reason I ask, for example as shown above, the form submission calls an HTTPS, and the site I'm on is HTTP only (no SSL).

A man-in-the-middle attack could rewrite the form to send the data elsewhere (or copy it elsewhere and let the submission continue to the intended site).

Comment: Man in the Middle - i.e. I am at a spoofed site?  Good point about Javascript, how could any user ever know they are safe?

Comment: More or less. A man in the middle gives you information from the original site, and sends data back to it, but monitors or manipulates the data in transit.

Comment: If users are on site A then (baring security weaknesses in site A) they can trust that the data they submit will be safe to the limit that they trust site A. If the form is on site A but being submitted to site B then they will be trusting site A (and hopefully sending the data to site B won't be an abuse of that trust). JavaScript doesn't make a difference because it is part of site A.

Answer (score 1):

The server that sent the form HTML (www.domain.com) will not see the submitted data.  That goes directly to DifferentSite.com, and is encrypted with DifferentSite.com's public key, so www.domain.com couldn't examine the data even if it received it.

Comment: Thanks Jim.  Let's pretend the form action was not encrypted.  Is it even possible for the server to see this form data?

Comment: No.  The data still goes over a different connection, between the client and DifferentSite.com.  www.domain.com will never be aware of the interaction.

Comment: This all assumes plain HTML, and that the web page doesn't contain JavaScript that ALSO sends data back to the originating site (www.domain.com).

Comment: With JS, how could any user EVER know they are safe?? ha